# Slingshot does not show Unity's app icon

Tags: applications, slingshot

I cannot figure out why slingshot is not showing and launching Unity 3D. I am using Elementary OS Freya.

Here is what I did:

Placed the file 'unity-editor.desktop' in '/usr/share/applications/'

The content of 'unity-editor.desktop' is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.0.0f0
Name=Unity
Exec=/usr/local/Unity/unity-editor-2017.2.0xb6Linux/Editor/Unity.sh
Icon=/usr/local/Unity/unity-editor-2017.2.0xb6Linux/unity-editor-  icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Development;IDE;Application;GNOME;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/com.unity3d.kharma;
```

After that I made the file executable with the command:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/share/applications/unity-editor.desktop
```

But yet I type 'unity' in slingshot, but still Unity is not launching.

Any help is welcome, thank you!